# Selenium Python Elemento no encontrado

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy haciendo un bot con Python3.9.5 y Selenium, quiero hacer click en un elemento `th` que es seleccionable, trate a traves de los métodos de Selenium acceder/encontrar el elemento mediante tag name, ID, XPATH, FULL XPATH, pero nada funciona. Además busqué respuestas en la documentación de Selenium sobre los tiempos de espera (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) pero aún así no logro resolverlo. Todo mi código funciona y encuentra los demas elementos excepto ese. Adjunto capturas de pantalla sobre lo sucedido y mi codigo.
IMPORTANTE: En la segunda captura de pantalla se puede observar que Entra por el try, sale por el except y el message del error aparece vacío en la consola.
[image: Ahi señalo el id del elemento th]

[image]

Mi codigo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

import requests
import lxml.html 
import pandas as pd


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
# Change user-data-dir path with your local path, where you want to save session
chrome_options.add_argument(
    f"user-data-dir=ruta-user-data")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\whatsapp-automation-master\\driver\\chromedriver.exe',
                          chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("URL")

login = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                        '//*[@id="userinput"]')
login.send_keys("*****")
print("Usuario escrito.")
time.sleep(2)


login_password = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                        '//*[@id="passwordinput"]')
login_password.send_keys("*****")
print("Contraseña escrita.")
time.sleep(2)

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                        '//*[@id="acceptbutton"]')
button.click()
print("Sesion iniciada.")
time.sleep(2)

button_admin = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                        '//*[@id="FrameworkMenu"]/ul/li[3]/a')
button_admin.click()
print("Boton de Pedidos")
time.sleep(2)

button_admin_pedidos = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                                '//*[@id="FrameworkMenu"]/ul/li[3]/ul/li[2]/a')

button_admin_pedidos.click()
print("Boton de Administracion de pedidos")
time.sleep(7)

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'jqgh_ConsultaPedido_grid_grilla_orden'))
    )
    element.click()
    print("Elemento encontrado.")

except Exception as e: 
    print(e)
    driver.quit()
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme de alguna forma urgentemente. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Estás recibiendo algún error? Cargalo a la respuesta

Comment: El mensaje de error aparece vacío en la consola

Comment: No tiene que haber mensaje de error. Ha habido un _timeout_, o sea, se ha producido un _TimeoutException_.

Comment: Y como lo resuelvo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empezaré suponiendo que el motivo por el cuál adjuntas la documentación de `Wait` de Selenium, es por el hecho de que cada acción, o ciertas acciones, realizada hace alguna petición y es por eso también que tienes tantos `time.sleep()`. Para evitar tener tantos sleep puedes usar

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\whatsapp-automation-master\\driver\\chromedriver.exe',
                          chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(15) # o bien el tiempo que veas que te sea necesario
driver.get("URL")
```

Así también omites usar

```
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'jqgh_ConsultaPedido_grid_grilla_orden'))
    )
```

Luego también según la captura del HTML el ID del elemento que quieres es `ConsultaPedido_grid_grilla_orden` pero en tu código estás buscando `jqgh_ConsultaPedido_grid_grilla_orden`. No sé si estoy en lo correcto o no, ya que el ID que estas buscando sí que existe.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("ConsultaPedido_grid_grilla_orden").click()
```

Me gustaría poder ver un mensaje de error, para saber qué está fallando. Porque por lo que estoy viendo, y entiendo, no veo el por qué te falla. Sí en este tiempo has dado con otro error o un mensaje de error, edita la pregunta y añade el error.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta @S. Wasta ahora con la linea de codigo que me proporcionaste me sale el siguiente error en consola `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="ConsultaPedido_grid_grilla_orden"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124`

Comment: El error lo lanza inmediatamente? Es decir, inicias el script y no hay como unos 15seg (los que he puesto de `implicit_wait(15)` en los que la consola se queda como "dormida/esperando"? Me está siendo un poco raro el error, y aunque fuese una tabla generada dinámicamente igualmente el `implicit_wait` seguiría solucionando el error, vamos así es como he probado, después de X segundos crear un botón y darle click a éste. Hay algo de lo que no me estoy percatando

Comment: No, el error no lo lanza inmediatamente, sino que tiene el tiempo de espera de 15 segundos tal cual como lo mencionas

Comment: Bffff... Se está haciendo mazo complejo para algo que es sencillo, y esto no tiene MD ni nada. Haciendo tú las acciones con el ratón, qué haces? Es decir, entras a la web, 1 click en el input del usuario, escribes el usuario. Click en el input del password, escribes el password. Click en login. ** Petición POST para validar usuario **. Click en pedidos. ** Petición para cargar los pedidos o la página correspondiente **. Y aquí es donde no encuentra el TH.

Comment: Abre el inspector web y ve a la consola y escribe un `document.querySelector("#ConsultaPedido_grid_grilla_orden").addEventListener("click", _ => console.log("CLICK"))` y luego haz click en el elemento ¿Te sale en la consola el `CLICK`?

Comment: Me sale que es null

Comment: Pero lo has puesto en donde la página que debe ser, no? Es decir, cuando ya tienes la tabla y es cuando debe hacer click en el TH

Comment: Intente en la consola exactamente la misma linea pero con distintos id y clases de elementos seleccionables como un boton, pero me sigue tirando null, tiene algo que ver que la pagina esta hecha en ASP.NET? Se que todo a "bajo nivel" funciona con HTML y Javascript en la web.

Comment: Así es lo intente en exactamente la misma pagina que debe ser

Comment: A mí parecer no creo que sea porque esté con ASP.net, ya que sí fuese así no podrías iniciar ni sesión o dar click al boton de pedidos, ¿me explico?. Intentaré buscar alguna web de ejemplo. con ASP.net Que ahora mismo estoy aburrido  y así hecho  un rato

Comment: Sisi por supuesto, te entiendo y muchas gracias

Comment: Ve a pastebin.com pega el tu código (omite los datos privados) y comparte el link porfa. Asegúrate de poner Paste Exposure como privado y si quiere que se elimine o algo, ya queda a tu criterio.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/LCLfPxgx

Comment: Perdón, era "unlisted". Que privado no deja verlo jajajaa

Comment: Listo, ya lo hice

Comment: Te importa  si te escribo por privado?

Comment: No hay problema, escribime así hablamos mejor